# mongo aggregation framework group by quarter/half year/year

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I have a database  with this schema structure :

```
{
    "name" : "Carl",
    "city" : "paris",
    "time" : "1-2018",
    "notes" : [ 
        "A", 
        "A", 
        "B", 
        "C", 
        "D"
    ]
}
```

And this query using the aggregation framework :

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate(
[{
    "$match": {
        "$and": [{
            "$or": [ {
                "time": "1-2018"
            }, {
                "time": "2-2018"
            } ]
        }, {
            "name": "Carl"
        }, {
            "city": "paris"
        }]
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$notes"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "notes": "$notes",
            "time": "$time"
        },
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}
, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.time",
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
        "time": "$_id",
        "count": 1
    }
}])
```

It working correcly and i'm getting these results these results :

```
{
    "count" : 4.0,
    "time" : "2-2018"
}

{
    "count" : 4.0,
    "time" : "1-2018"
}
```

My issue is that i'd like to keep the same match stage and i'd like to group by quarter.

Here the result i'd like to have :

```
{
    "count" : 8.0,
    "time" : "1-2018"  // here quarter 1
}
```

Thanks